# CouchDB summarise data for pie chart

Tags: couchdb

I have following document in my CouchDB database:-

```
{
   "_id": "c0d93b8f424037583b2fe71ea403044a",
   "name": "Joe",
   "country": "United Kingdom",
   "email": "joe@acme.com"
}
{
   "_id": "c0d93b8f424037583b2fe71ea403044d",
   "name": "Joe",
   "country": "United Kingdom",
   "email": "joe@acme.com"
}
{
   "_id": "c0d93b8f424037583b2fe71ea403044z",
   "name": "Joe",
   "country": "United Kingdom",
   "email": "joe@acme.com"
}
{
   "_id": "c0d93b8f424037583b2fe71ea403044x",
   "name": "Fred",
   "country": "France",
   "email": "Fred@acme.com"
}
{
   "_id": "c0d93b8f424037583b2fe71ea403044g",
   "name": "Fred",
   "country": "France",
   "email": "Fred@acme.com"
}
{
   "_id": "c0d93b8f424037583b2fe71ea403044p",
   "name": "Bill",
   "country": "Germany",
   "email": "Bill@acme.com"
}
```

I want to summarise this data so that I can produce a pie chart based on the countries, but I'm struggling to work out the map reduce code to obtain the document count by country.

Could somebody shed a little light on this for me please.

Best Regards,

Carlskii

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty simple.

Your map function just emits the *country* as a key and *1* as a value.

```js
function(doc) {
  if (doc.country) {
    emit(doc.country, 1);
  }
}
```

Now your reduce function is just the [built-in](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) `_sum` function.

Query your view with the `group_level` parameter setting it to 1.

> GET /db/_design/app/_view/bycountry?group_level=1`

Your result should look like this.

```
{
    "rows": [
        {"key": "France", "value": 2},
        {"key": "Germany", "value": 1},
        {"key": "United Kingdom", "value": 3}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this, if you need the grand total, just call the same query, except use `group=false` instead of `group_level`.

Comment: You can also use `group=true` instead of `group_level=1`, which will do exactly the same thing in this case. That way, all you need to do is toggle `group` between `true` and `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. However, when I tried the above query
like this it returns:

{"error":"query_parse_error","reason":"Invalid URL parameter 'group' or  'group_level' for non-reduce view."}

Comment: Sounds like you didn't add a reduce function. I've added some more information to my answer.